# ggplot R multiple histogram with same scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following melted `data.frame`:

```
   stazione         variable value
1         c perc_dati_validi   100
2         i perc_dati_validi   100
3         c              min     6
4         i              min     6
5         c              max    75
6         i              max   105
7         c            media    25
8         i            media    39
9         c               50    24
10        i               50    39
11        c               90    42
12        i               90    60
13        c               95    47
14        i               95    68
15        c               98    53
16        i               98    77
```

I would like to plot the different numeric variables grouped by `stazione`.
I'm using:

```
ggplot(tab22m, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=stazione))+geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

The result is the following:
[ggplot2 plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DttGB.png)

The y scale is messed up. I'd wish it to start at zero and end at 105.
Any idea?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue.

```
ggplot(tab22m, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=stazione)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

produces

[image]

Make sure that `value` is actually a `numeric` or `integer` vector (check with `str(tab22m)`); perhaps somehow `value` got turned into a `factor`?

---

### Sample data

```
tab22m <- read.table(text =
    "   stazione         variable value
1         c perc_dati_validi   100
2         i perc_dati_validi   100
3         c              min     6
4         i              min     6
5         c              max    75
6         i              max   105
7         c            media    25
8         i            media    39
9         c               50    24
10        i               50    39
11        c               90    42
12        i               90    60
13        c               95    47
14        i               95    68
15        c               98    53
16        i               98    77", header = T)
```

Comment: You are right, it was a factor! I lost so much on this and now it works! Thank you!